# Cannot create log files in non-local docker containers due to permission errors

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, file-permissions

I am having issues creating log files in multiple different docker containers (rabbitmq container, rabbit mongodb BE, and my 2 asynchronous task scheduler services) on my server due to permission errors. I believe it may have something to do with the architecture on which I run the docker containers, reason being, I have no issues when they are brought up on my mac m1 (arm64 ?), but as soon as I attempt to run them on my server (amd64 ?), each container fails to create log files. I will use rabbitmq container, and mongodb container as an example:

docker-compose:

```
  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    volumes:
      - ./data/rabbitmq_logs:/var/log/rabbitmq
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"

  rabbit_mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data/rabbit_mongodb_logs:/var/log/mongodb
    command: 
      - '--logpath'
      - '/var/log/mongodb/rabbit_mongodb_log.log'
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

.env:

```
RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE=/var/log/rabbitmq
RABBITMQ_LOGS=${RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE}/rabbit_log.log
RABBITMQ_SASL_LOGS=${RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE}/rabbit_sasl_log.log
```

mongodb error logs:

```
rabbit_mongodb_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-04T16:22:14.797Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":38,"codeName":"FileNotOpen","errmsg":"Can't initialize rotatable log file :: caused by :: Failed to open /var/log/mongodb/rabbit_mongodb_log.log"}}}
cntautomation-private_rabbit_mongodb_1 exited with code 1
```

rabbitmq error logs:

```
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:28.227565+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:28.327521+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:28.327573+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:28.327596+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:28.327623+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] stream_queue
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:28.327726+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:28.327744+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:28.327768+00:00 [info] <0.222.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:30.826617+00:00 [noti] <0.44.0> Application syslog exited with reason: stopped
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:30.826709+00:00 [noti] <0.222.0> Logging: switching to configured handler(s); following messages may not be visible in this log output
rabbit_1          |
rabbit_1          | BOOT FAILED
rabbit_1          | ===========
rabbit_1          | failed to open log file at '/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbit_upgrade.log', reason: permission denied
rabbit_1          |
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:31.039651+00:00 [erro] <0.222.0>
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:31.039651+00:00 [erro] <0.222.0> BOOT FAILED
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:31.039651+00:00 [erro] <0.222.0> ===========
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:31.039651+00:00 [erro] <0.222.0> failed to open log file at '/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbit_upgrade.log', reason: permission denied
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:31.039651+00:00 [erro] <0.222.0>
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>   crasher:
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     initial call: application_master:init/4
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     pid: <0.221.0>
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     registered_name: []
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     exception exit: {{cannot_log_to_file,
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>                          "/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbit_upgrade.log",eacces},
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>                      {rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>       in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 142)
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     ancestors: [<0.220.0>]
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     message_queue_len: 1
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     messages: [{'EXIT',<0.222.0>,normal}]
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     links: [<0.220.0>,<0.44.0>]
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     dictionary: []
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     trap_exit: true
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     status: running
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     heap_size: 610
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     stack_size: 29
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>     reductions: 177
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>   neighbours:
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.043686+00:00 [erro] <0.221.0>
rabbit_1          | 2021-11-04 16:22:32.067915+00:00 [noti] <0.44.0> Application rabbit exited with reason: {{cannot_log_to_file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbit_upgrade.log",eacces},{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}
rabbit_1          | {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbit,{{cannot_log_to_file,\"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbit_upgrade.log\",eacces},{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
rabbit_1          | Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbit,{{cannot_log_to_file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbit_upgrade.log",eacces},{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}})
rabbit_1          |
rabbit_1          | Crash dump is being written to: /var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump...cntautomation-private_rabbit_1 exited with code 0
```

Again, there are no issues when brought up on my local development server (mac m1) but when trying to bring up on the server (aws lightsail instance), I am having these issues. This is happening with most of my services. I am not super familiar on properly managing permissions, so is there some workaround that I could use, or maybe I am missing something entirely?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE:

It is more likely the case that the mounted volume that is getting created is created as root:

```
drwxr-xr-x 8 root   root   4096 Nov  4 22:32 data
```

and all log directories within the data directory also have permissions set for root.

When entering task scheduling services I see that the logs directory created has permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Nov  4 22:32 logs
```

but on my mac it has:

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 nobody nogroup  288 Nov  4 21:40 logs
```

which is what I set the ownership to in the Dockerfile and the user as for the service in docker-compose file.

```
  worker:
    build: 
      context: ./services/website
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.celery
    user: nobody
    entrypoint: celery -A src.celery.celery:celery worker --loglevel INFO
    volumes:
      - ./data/worker_logs:/usr/src/app/logs
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DEPLOYMENT_TYPE=development
      - LOG_FILE=./logs/worker_logs.log
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
      - web
      - rabbit_mongodb
    restart: on-failure:10
```

```
FROM python:3.9.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN chown nobody:nogroup ./
RUN ln -s /run/shm /dev/shm

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/logs
RUN chown nobody:nogroup /usr/src/app/logs
```

It seems like the Docker container is taking the permissions of the mounted volume from the server, but it does not do that on my mac. How am I supposed to set permissions for my docker containers and properly manage these mounted volumes? Note that the default user for aws lightsail instances is "ubuntu".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your rabbitMQ directory has no permissions. In my case, it was in /opt/rabbitmq and I solve it this way:

```
chmod 666 -R /opt/rabbitmq
```